# Search for events + location + keyword + period on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to search for public events on Facebook which includes these parameters:

- Location
- Keyword
- Period (month of September let's say)

Thnx!

Comment: No that is not possible

Comment: And is keyword + location only possible?

Comment: And is there some way to sort basic keyword search results based on entry date?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search - that’s all there is (and it ain’t much.)

Comment: Is there perhaps someway to scrape it your self with a bot or something?